# How do I configure Azure SSO between two Azure AD Instances?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am very new to SSO and am having trouble enabling cross company SSO. I work on a React SPA and used the MSAL React Library to implement SSO for our application. I created a non-gallery Enterprise Application in Azure, and used that subscription information to validate users on the application during login. This is all working as expected.

After providing our SAML SSO configuration to companyB, the user at companyB cannot sign on and is getting the following error...

"Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'XYZ' and cannot access the application '123-456-789' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account."

To me, that means I need to manually add the user who is attempting to log in, but that would negate the usefulness of integrating the two Azure ADs. I've provided all of my SAML configuration to companyB, and still no luck. What could I be missing?

In order to create the link between the two Azure ADs, the user just needs to create a non gallery application with SAML SSO enabled and the SAML config, right? Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After some more reading I am wondering if I should have done a regular App Registration to my Azure AD instead of an Enterprise Application...

Answer (score 0):

I realized my code was configured to only work for one tenant, pointing to the common login endpoint solved this issue.